# newff, different numbers of hidden layers but get the same result

Tags: neural-network, matlab

I'm trying to compare the result of newff with different number of hidden layer but the result is the same. I used 1 hidden layer and 2 hidden layers to compare.

```
net = newff( minmax( pn ), [5 1], {'tansig' 'purelin'}, 'trainlm');
net = newff( minmax( pn ), [5 5 1], {'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'}, 'trainlm');
```

code:

```
load data.txt;
P = data(1:20,1:3);
T = data(1:20,4);
[a,minp,maxp,b,mint,maxt] = premnmx(P',T');
net = newff( minmax( pn ), [5 1], {'tansig' 'purelin'}, 'trainlm');
net.trainParam.epochs = 10000;
net.trainParam.show = 5;
net = train(net,a,b);
y = sim(net,a)
x = postmnmx(y',mint,maxt);
plot(x, 'r');
hold
plot(T);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: the y answer from y=sim(net,a) for 1 hidden layer and 2 hidden layers are the same... suppose the result must be different mean 2 hidden layers result should be better than 1 hidden layer.. is it correct?

Comment: not necessarily, although with sufficiently complex data that would usually be the case. How many samples do you have for training?

Comment: i used 20 samples for the input.

Comment: in that case I wouldn't assume anything like that. Try feeding synthetic data to the network, preferably something that a three-layer model could model exactly, but a two-layer one could not.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to use a GUI based matlab command nprtools for neural networks.